# How to align objects vertically in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have been messing around with asp.net for awhile now and always have issues aligning objects with various heights on the same row. For example, in this case, I have a search label, a text field, then a image button. What is the "proper way" to get these three items to align properly?

My existing code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
   </asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Panel VerticalAlign="Center" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="Search Tests:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" 
        Height="30px" style="margin-left: 13px; margin-top: 0px" Width="219px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="45px" 
        ImageUrl="~/Images/SearchButton.PNG" style="margin-left: 18px; margin-top: 0px" 
        Width="95px" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: ASP and ASP.NET are not the same thing.  You should get in the habit of using the two terms correctly or you might not get the answer you expect.

Comment: This question has very little to do with ASP.NET. It's pretty  much an HTML question. Figure out how to do it with plain HTML, and  you'll have your answer.

Comment: @Abe I'm sorry. I will keep this in mind when posting in the future. Thanks for correcting the issue for me this time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest is using CSS or tables.  I put a div around with a height and vertical align to the top.  [CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/default.asp)

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" VerticalAlign="Center" runat="server">
        <div style="height: 40px; vertical-align: top">
            <div style="padding-top: 10px; float:left;">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Text="Search Tests:"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top: 5px; float:left;">
                <asp:TextBox ID="searchTextBox" runat="server" Font-Size="X-Large" Height="30px"
                     Style="margin-left: 13px; margin-top: 0px" Width="219px"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top: 5px; float:left;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" Height="45px" ImageUrl="~/Images/SearchButton.PNG"
                     Style="margin-left: 18px; margin-top: 0px" Width="95px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate the response. However, that all three items are still aligning based on their vertical bottom. Is there a way to make the middle of the three objects align? I apologize if this desire was not clear in my question

Comment: I've modified the code to reflect this: You would need to put each one in their own div tag and adjust the padding-top to make them line up.  The only problem with that is cross browser they may not all line up perfectly, they should be very close but not exactly the same on each browser.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. Is that how most sites handle this sort of thing? I feel like wanting to align such objects would be a common concern.

Comment: Yep that's exactly how most if not all do it.  CSS is more than standard now because it's more flexible than tables.  It use to be put everything in tables but then you get a very boxy layout and some very ugly code.  Good Luck.

Comment: @Robart. Awesome. Thanks for all the help and info. I still have much to learn about css and HTML, but I am excited to get started.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and i think that using a table or a div only to align the Textbox it's excessive.

I solved simply:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="~/imatges/imgNou.png"
                 CssClass="style3" ImageAlign="AbsBottom" />
```

And adding the `margin-top` in Design view, the IDE added:

```
.style3
{
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```